# check words sequence regexp

Tags: php, regex

I have some text and have to check is it valid or no.

> fddfgdfgfdg  phrase here **first**
>
> sdafdsafdsa
>
> sadfsadf
>
> sadfdsaf
>
> phrase here **second**

I have to check in this text the correct sequence. 
Word FIRST must be in text before word SECOND. We know only these two words and don't know the rest text. So "first ANY TEXT second" - valid, "second ANY TEXT first" - not valid.

I wrote a regexp [`/^.*?\n*?first.*?|\n*?second.*?\n*?$/mg`](https://regex101.com/r/Q0XJQj/2), but in finds words in any sequence.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `/^.*?\n*?first.*?|\n*?second.*?\n*?$/mg` regex will match `first` and `second` separately, without considering the order since the pattern consists of 2 alternatives, 1) `^.*?\n*?first.*?` that matches start of a line, any 0+ chars up to 0+ newlines and then `first` and 2) `\n*?second.*?\n*?$` that matches 0+ newlines, `second` then any 0+ chars up to optional newlines and end of line. Actually, the pattern is certainly a bit off.

You may use the following regex:

```
'~first.*second~s'
```

See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/zFAbJG/1)

Use with `preg_match`. The pattern will find `first` and then  `second` somewhere after `first` across multiple lines due to the `s` modifier.

An efficient alternative *unrolled* regex is [`'~first[^s]*(?:s(?!econd)[^s]*)*second~'`](https://regex101.com/r/zFAbJG/2) that will find `first` and then `second` after it.

See [PHP demo](https://ideone.com/aL8FpL)

```
$re = '~first.*second~s';
$str = "fddfgdfgfdg  phrase here first\nsdafdsafdsa\nsadfsadf\nsadfdsaf\nphrase here second";
if (preg_match($re, $str, $matches)) {
    echo "Valid!";
}
```

If the `first` and `second` are whole alphanumeric words, enclose with word boundaries: `\bfirst\b` and `\bsecond\b`.

Answer (score 1):

You could use `strpos` to check for the words.

```
if (strpos($string, '**first**') !== false && strpos($string, '**second**') !== false && strpos($string, '**first**') < strpos($string, '**second**')) {
    // String contains both words, first before the second
}
```